# Logical and +Inf in R

Tags: r

What should be the result of `is.logical(+Inf)?`

```
> as.logical(+Inf)
[1] TRUE
> Inf==TRUE
[1] FALSE
> Inf==FALSE
[1] FALSE
```

I was exploring the idea of 'what is equivalent to TRUE'. In R, I thought every non-zero number was equivalent to TRUE.  I expected +Inf to be equivalent to logical NA (neither true nor false), and the second two comparisons seem to confirm that. But then how do I explain the '`as.logical`' result being TRUE if it won't compare to TRUE?

> Mods: I made a reasonable, good faith effort, to look for duplicates of this question before posting. I tried searching under the keywords "Inf" and "logical".  I found some results for C++, but not for R.  If this comes up a dup, I'd REALLY like to know how I could have searched for and found it first. ]

Comment: as.logical converts every non-zero, non-NA number to TRUE. In the comparison, TRUE is coerced to 1. You cannot compare with Inf like this. Use is.finite.

Comment: Inf and -Inf are not numbers. (I don't remember seeing this question before, but you might try to search the Rhelp archives.)

Comment: I'm thinking there's some inconsistency here. Look at `Inf || FALSE` which returns
`[1] TRUE`, as does `TRUE && Inf`

Comment: @42- No inconsistency. `||` and `&&` must coerce to logical, whereas `==` coerces to a common data type that can represent both sides (in order logical < integer < ... < character). See also `help("==")`.

Comment: @roland - I'm not sure what you mean by "can't" since I executed the above and returned an answer.  So, I certainly "can", but the results may not be what I expect.

Comment: @42 - As for your comment that +Inf and -Inf are not numbers, R seems to disagree, witness :

is.numeric(+Inf)`
[1] TRUE`

The notion of +Inf is that it is supposed to represent a "limiting form" , and be able to act like a number in arithmetic operations.

Comment: @roland - I think your comment about ||, &&, and == is the answer I seek.  Can you submit it as the solution, and I'll upvote it?

Comment: @Roland So you're saying '==' coerces TRUE to 1, rather than coercing Inf to TRUE. I guess the rules for coercion isn't completely clear to me. What then prevents both from being coerced to character? (I do understand that would create havoc and would not be a good thing, but I cannot find the help page (although I know that I have seen it multiple times) that describes the coercion logic in base R. `?coerce` sends us to `?setAs` which is focused on S$ function behavior.

Comment: @42- It looks up which side is higher in order of precedence and coerces to that data type. It's probably also described in the language definition.

Comment: Thanks, and the Language Def doc may be where I've seen it.